# Amazon SQS DLQ : Are sqs messages older than 14days moved to DLQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

How does the Amazon SQS's DLQ work when it comes to old messages? 
Do messages older than 14days() get moved to DLQ instead of being deleted ?
I dont see any documentation relating to how older messages are handled.

From the documentation it looks like just the errored messages are moved to DLQ, is my assumption right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding is correct; Messages that are older than the retention period you have set (max of 14 days), will be deleted, not moved to the DLQ.

> SQS automatically deletes messages that have been in a queue for more
>   than maximum message retention period. The default message retention
>   period is 4 days. However, you can set the message retention period to
>   a value from 60 seconds to 1209600 seconds (14 days) with
>   SetQueueAttributes.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MessageLifecycle.html

Answer (score -2):

All the messages that are not processed/consumed will gets pushed to DLQ.
`Amazon SQS supports dead-letter queues (DLQ), which other queues (source queues) can target for messages that can't be processed (consumed) successfully.` 
Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html

Comment: Wrong answer! Only messages not consumed successfully (received and deleted within the visibility timeout) within the maximum receive are moved to DLQ.

For example, if the consumer is down the messages will never be "received" so they not be moved to DLQ and will be deleted when retention ends (max 14 days).